# biblatex APA style shortens to "..." instead of "et al." in reference list

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm writing my (German) thesis with `biblatex-apa` and came across this problem.

An article I cite has 13 authors. When cited, it shows in the reference list with all the names included. I want to shorten it to 6 names and add "et al." after the sixth name.

So I know I can manipulate the number of names shown in the reference list with `apamaxprtauth = 6` but unfortunately that just fills in "..." between the sixth and last author and no et al. (which seems kinda weird to me?):

[image: Picture of the unwanted output with dots]

What i want is the output to be like this:

> One, A., Two, A., Three, A., Four, A., Five, A., Six, A. et al. (2020). Important title of important article. Important Journal, 44, 1–16.

extract from my `.tex` file

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber,
   apamaxprtauth=6, 
   natbib=true, 
   language=ngerman, 
   doi=true,            
   uniquename=init
   ]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}}  
\addbibresource{../literature.bib}


\begin{document}
      bla bla bla \textcite{lit1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file entry

```
  @article{lit1,
   author = {Author One and Author Two and Author Three and Author Four and Author    
     Five and Author Six and Author Seven and Author Eight and Author Nine and Author
     Ten and Author Eleven and Author Twelve and Author Thirteen},
   journal = {Important Journal},
   pages = {1--16},
   title = {Important title of important article},
   volume = {44},
   year = {2020}}
```

Comment: The output you are showing is expected in (and mandated by) APA style. Since `biblatex-apa` was written to exactly follow APA guidelines it would be quite complicated to change this behaviour.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, but unless your version of `biblatex-apa` is really outdated you won't need the `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}`. The option `language=ngerman,` in the `biblatex` call is also superfluous here and usually does not do what people expect unless other options are also activated. I would remove it. The option `uniquename=init` is already pre-set if you use `style=apa,`, so I would also drop it.

Comment: @moewe thanks for letting me know, i decluttered it as you said and it worked fine - so no outdated version :) 

maybe i just have to ask my supervisor for letting this slip. it's one of the few apa-altered rules for writing psychology texts in german...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general form of the output you are showing is expected in (and mandated by) APA style.

The current 7th edition of the APA style manual shows up to 19 names before it starts replacing names with `...`, see https://apastyle.apa.org/blog/more-than-20-authors and https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/elements-list-entry#author. The 6th edition of APA style showed up to 6 names before it started replacing names with `...`.

Since `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-apa6` are written to exactly follow APA guidelines, it is quite tricky to change this behaviour (because `biblatex-apa` needs to do quite some work to implement the unusual APA style behaviour in the first place). In particular the standard methods to change the number of names shown in the bibliography (`maxbibnames`, `minbibnames` and friends) will not work as expected in `biblatex-apa`.

With a current version of `biblatex-apa` (tested with v9.14 from 2020-08-28), the following should work. The idea is to change the two primary `biblatex-apa` name formats from [their original definitions in `apa.bbx` (ll. 529-574 in v9.14)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/296615f83fbf07f94b64c9cff50df40cddb9ddf0/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/bbx/apa.bbx#L529-L574) to only print something for the first `\maxprtauth` names possibly followed by "et al.". The code for `apa:andothers` is adapted [from `name:andothers` (`biblatex.def`, ll. 1128-1138 in v3.15a)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/e5d6e69e61613cc33ab1fcc2083a8277eb9cfce5/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1128-L1138)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=apa,
  apamaxprtauth=6,
  doi=true,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareNameFormat{apaauthor}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{name:apa:family-given}%
       {\namepartfamily}%
       {\namepartgiven}%
       {\namepartgiveni}%
       {\namepartprefix}%
      {\namepartsuffix}%
     \usebibmacro{role}{\addspace}{\mkbibparens}%
     \hasitemannotation[\currentname][username]
       {\addspace\mkbibbrackets{\getitemannotation[\currentname][username]}}
       {}}%
  \usebibmacro{apa:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{apanames}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{name:apa:given-family}%
       {\namepartfamily}%
       {\namepartgiven}%
       {\namepartgiveni}%
       {\namepartprefix}%
       {\namepartsuffix}%
     \usebibmacro{role}{\addcomma\space}{\@firstofone}}%
  \usebibmacro{apa:andothers}}
\makeatother

\newbibmacro*{apa:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\maxprtauth}}
    and
    (
       test \ifmorenames
       or
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{listtotal}}{\maxprtauth}}
     )
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \printdelim{andothersdelim}\bibstring{andothers}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lit1,
  author  = {Author One and Author Two and Author Three and Author Four
             and Author Five and Author Six and Author Seven
             and Author Eight and Author Nine and Author Ten
             and Author Eleven and Author Twelve and Author Thirteen},
  journal = {Important Journal},
  pages   = {1--16},
  title   = {Important title of important article},
  volume  = {44},
  year    = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
  bla bla bla \textcite{lit1,sigfridsson,worman,aksin,companion}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: One, A., Two, A., Three, A., Four, A., Five, A., Six, A. et al. (2020). Important title of important article. Important Journal, 44, 1–16.]

Note that I cleaned up some of the options and other `biblatex`-related code mentioned [in my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577037/biblatex-apa-style-shortens-to-instead-of-et-al-in-reference-list/577039#comment1452738_577037) in the MWE.

> Unrelated to your actual problem, but unless your version of `biblatex-apa` is really outdated you won't need the `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}`.
> The option `language=ngerman,` in the `biblatex` call is also superfluous here and usually does not do what people expect unless other options are also activated. I would remove it.
> The option `uniquename=init` is already pre-set if you use `style=apa,`, so I would also drop it.